# Limit Messages Included in Outlook Conversations

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'm using Outlook 2010 on Desktop, and I have huge amounts of conversations that date back from 2013. It seems that Outlook build conversations by adding all the messages when they are answered and/or transfered via meetings or other replies.

But then I've got some conversations that have 100 or more items. And when I receive a new message, Outlook takes some time to display the whole conversation and it makes my laptop lag.

I have a i5-4200U and 4 Go of RAM by the way.

I want to limit that laggy effect by limiting the number of message that Outlook adds (or displays) in a conversation. I would want for instance that all of my conversations have a maximum amount of 10 messages.

Is that doable?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to specifically limit the number of messages to show in a conversation. However, you can get close to this behavior by limiting the number of messages eligible for inclusion in the conversation by using a [Search Folder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-messages-or-items-with-a-Search-Folder-24e1a8e4-dfb6-4662-bf37-ea769925f094):

> A Search Folder is a virtual folder that provides a view of all email items that match specific search criteria. For example, the Unread Mail Search Folder enables you to view all unread messages in one folder, even though the messages might be saved in different folders.

A custom Search Folder can limit the messages it displays, perhaps by date.

Like regular folders, search folders can display messages as conversions and you can perform all normal operations on messages, such as Replying, Moving to another folder, Deleting, etc.

**To Create a Custom Search Folder:**

1. In Mail, on the Folder tab, in the New group, click New Search
2. From the Select a Search Folder list, click Create a custom Search Folder
3. Under Customize Search Folder, click Choose
4. Type a name for your custom Search Folder.
5. Click Criteria, and then select the options that you want.
6. Click Browse, select the folders that you want to be searched.
7. Click OK to close each open dialog box.